# Change array that might contain None to an array that contains "" in python

Tags: python, string

I have a python function that gets an array called row.

Typically row contains things like:

```
["Hello","goodbye","green"]
```

And I print it with:

```
print "\t".join(row)
```

Unfortunately, sometimes it contains:

```
["Hello",None,"green"]
```

Which generates this error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string or Unicode, NoneType found
```

Is there an easy way to replace any None elements with ""?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
>>> l = ["Hello", None, "green"]
>>> [(x if x is not None else '') for x in l]
['Hello', '', 'green']
```

A slightly shorter way is:

```
>>> [x or '' for x in l]
```

But note that the second method also changes 0 and some other objects to the empty string.

Comment: Pretty slick; when did python get "if" as an operator?

Comment: Since the result is just going to be consumed by `str.join`, it could make a lot of sense to use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension. Consider using round brackets instead of square brackets in line 2 of the answer.

Comment: It turns out that it is more efficient to use `[` than `(`. You always got to benchmark it to see what's best:
```>>> timeit.timeit('" ".join([x for x in ["A","B","C","D","E"]])',number=1000000)
0.9901980350259691
>>> timeit.timeit('" ".join((x for x in ["A","B","C","D","E"]))',number=1000000)
1.1486009320942685
>>> 
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression in place of the array:

```
print "\t".join(fld or "" for fld in row)
```

This will substitute the empty string for everything considered as `False` (None, False, 0, 0.0, ''…).

Comment: I didn't know that Python let you use "or" like that at this point. Neat. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the built-in filter function:

```
>>> l = ["Hello", None, "green"]
>>> filter(None, l)
['Hello', 'green']
```

Comment: This may not be a good solution to this particular problem. The question mentions that the tab character `\t` is to be used as the separator. Removing an element of the list outright may lead to one fewer tab character being emitted.

Comment: This doesn't do what I want ,because the output list has a different number of elements than the input list.